# Use XCode's ${PRODUCT_NAME} inside header files

Tags: xcode

I have a generic header file that I include in every project. Among other things, it defines a preprocessor macro for easily obtaining a reference to the app delegate. The problem is, the class name of the app delegate changes from project to project, as it includes the product name (AppDelegate). Therefore I wonder if it's somehow possible to use ${PRODUCT_NAME}, or a similar macro construct, in header files?

Comment: I suppose you'll have to create a custom runscript which will replace it in your header file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set Preprocessor Macros in Xcode Build Settings.

```
APPDELEGATE_CLASS=$(PRODUCT_NAME)AppDelegate
```

In xcconfig,

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = APPDELEGATE_CLASS=$(PRODUCT_NAME)AppDelegate
```

Then you can use APPDELEGATE_CLASS macro in your code.

```
@interface APPDELEGATE_CLASS : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
```